# How to change date format from '1965-08-01 00:00:00.0' to 'Tue Aug 01 00:00:00 PDT 2000' in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('1965-08-01 00:00:00.0','Dy Mon DD HH:MM:ss TZD YYYY') from dual;
```

i have data in wrong format in varchar column as below mentioned.

```
1973-12-12 00:00:00.0
2003-05-14 00:00:00.0
1950-05-01 00:00:00.0
Fri Jul 01 00:00:00 PDT 1977
Sun Feb 01 00:00:00 PST 2015
Wed May 14 00:00:00 PDT 2003
```

I want to keep all date in same format as below but not able to convert.

```
Fri Jul 01 00:00:00 PDT 1977
Sun Feb 01 00:00:00 PST 2015
Wed May 14 00:00:00 PDT 2003
```

When adding `'Dy Mon DD HH:MM:ss TZD YYYY'` format then getting exception not valid date format due to TZD.

Can any one help me to convert this date and keep in same format through update query.

Comment: This is why you shouldn't store dates/timestamps as strings. Do you only have those two formats? Also your first query throws "ORA-01846: not a valid day of the week", not something about the TZD? What time zone are you assuming the first three rows are in - and/or what time zone do you want to convert the last three rows to?

Comment: i am expecting PST for all those are not in correct format

Answer (score 0):

Storing dates or timestamps as strings is not a good idea. You should make your columns the correct datatype for the data they will hold. As well as allowing Oracle to be more efficient, it prevents you storing invalid data.

However, if you just want to convert strings like `'1965-08-01 00:00:00.0'` to `'Tue Aug 01 00:00:00 PDT 2000'` so they are all in the same string format you can convert those values to timestamps with `to_timestamp()`, specify which time zone they represent with `from_tz()`, and then convert them back to string in the format you want. With a demo table `t` built with your sample data:

```
update t set str = to_char(from_tz(to_timestamp(str, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'),
  'America/Los_Angeles'), 'Dy Mon DD HH24:MI:SS TZD YYYY')
where str not like '%PDT%' and str not like '%PST%';

3 rows updated.

select * from t;

STR                        
----------------------------
Wed Dec 12 00:00:00 PST 1973
Wed May 14 00:00:00 PDT 2003
Mon May 01 00:00:00 PDT 1950
Fri Jul 01 00:00:00 PDT 1977
Sun Feb 01 00:00:00 PST 2015
Wed May 14 00:00:00 PDT 2003

 6 rows selected
```

You need to apply a filter so it ignores any rows that are already in the target format, since those would error. Here I've excluded any that contain PDT or PST. If you have other formats you haven't shown you could use `regexp_like()` to look for rows that exactly match a specific format instead.

---

More generally, to convert any of your strings to actual timestamps you can create a function that tries various formats and returns the first one that successfully converts, by trapping exceptions. A simple brute force approach might be:

```
create or replace function my_to_timestamp_tz(p_str varchar2)
return timestamp with time zone as
begin
  -- try each expected pattern in turn

  begin
    return to_timestamp_tz(p_str, 'Dy Mon DD HH24:MI:SS TZD YYYY');
  exception
    when others then
      null;
  end;

  begin
    -- unspecified TZ; this assumes same as server
    return to_timestamp_tz(p_str, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF');
  exception
    when others then
      null;
  end;

  -- maybe throw an exception if no conversions worked
  return null;
end;
/
```

PDT/PST isn't always recognised; I have two DBs that I thought were built the same but one allows that and other throws "ORA-01857: not a valid time zone". If you see that too you can work around it by treating the TZD value as a fixed string and specifying which region it represents:

```
  -- if your DB doesn't recognise PDT/PST then force them to a region:
  begin
    return from_tz(to_timestamp_tz(p_str, 'Dy Mon DD HH24:MI:ss "PDT" YYYY'),
      'America/Los_Angeles');
  exception
    when others then
      null;
  end;

  begin
    return from_tz(to_timestamp_tz(p_str, 'Dy Mon DD HH24:MI:ss "PST" YYYY'),
      'America/Los_Angeles');
  exception
    when others then
      null;
  end;

  -- other time zone abbreviations and matching regions if you expect any
```

Using that function:

```
with t (str) as (
  select '1973-12-12 00:00:00.0' from dual
  union all select '2003-05-14 00:00:00.0' from dual
  union all select '1950-05-01 00:00:00.0' from dual
  union all select 'Fri Jul 01 00:00:00 PDT 1977' from dual
  union all select 'Sun Feb 01 00:00:00 PST 2015' from dual
  union all select 'Wed May 14 00:00:00 PDT 2003' from dual
)
select str, my_to_timestamp_tz(str) as converted
from t;

STR                          CONVERTED                                          
---------------------------- ----------------------------------------------------
1973-12-12 00:00:00.0        1973-12-12 00:00:00 Europe/London                   
2003-05-14 00:00:00.0        2003-05-14 00:00:00 Europe/London                   
1950-05-01 00:00:00.0        1950-05-01 00:00:00 Europe/London                   
Fri Jul 01 00:00:00 PDT 1977 1977-07-01 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles             
Sun Feb 01 00:00:00 PST 2015 2015-02-01 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles             
Wed May 14 00:00:00 PDT 2003 2003-05-14 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles
```

Notice that the first three assume a time zone, and because I'm running this in the UK pick London. If that isn't going to give the right result for you and you know those always represent a specific time zone, you can can specify that zone by changing the last block in the function to do:

```
  begin
    -- unspecified TZ; assume from a specific region
    return from_tz(to_timestamp(p_str, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'),
      'America/Los_Angeles');
  exception
  ...
```

which will then get:

```
STR                          CONVERTED                                          
---------------------------- ----------------------------------------------------
1973-12-12 00:00:00.0        1973-12-12 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles             
2003-05-14 00:00:00.0        2003-05-14 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles             
1950-05-01 00:00:00.0        1950-05-01 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles             
Fri Jul 01 00:00:00 PDT 1977 1977-07-01 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles             
Sun Feb 01 00:00:00 PST 2015 2015-02-01 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles             
Wed May 14 00:00:00 PDT 2003 2003-05-14 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles
```

If you really want to you can convert the generated timestamps back to strings, but I'd really recommend you store them as the right data type

Comment: Thanks Alex for quick response. We are keeping change log in this field hence some time it may store text also for other category..  Still this is not work for as i have 20 million records and all are different format. I wanted to keep all in Fri Jul 01 00:00:00 PDT 1977 format only

Comment: @rohitchandra - I've added a more straightfoward update to just change one format to the other. I misinterpreted the question I think.